# param is missing or the value is empty: order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am creating an order from the API in rails 4. When I create the order in my create action, I could not figure out this below error.

```
Started POST "/api/v1/orders?access_token=testing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-22 12:23:55 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::OrdersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"access_token"=>"testing"}
  ApiKey Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `api_keys`.* FROM `api_keys`  WHERE `api_keys`.`access_token` = 'testing' LIMIT 1
  Restaurant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `restaurants`.* FROM `restaurants`  WHERE `restaurants`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1


ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: order:
```

My controller code:

**Orders_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::OrdersController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.json? }
before_action :fetch_restaurent
before_action :fetch_food_items, :only => [:index]

after_action :send_order_to_kitchen, :only => [:create, :update]


  def app_sync
  end

  def index
    @orders = Restaurant.orders.fetch_items_from_ethor
  end

  def show
   # Display the list of food_items available from the restaurant
   # Allow the customer to place an order 
  end

    def create
        @order = Order.build(order_params)
        if @order.save
            render :json, order, status:201, location: [:api, current_customer, order]
        else
            render :json, { errors: order.errors }, status:422
        end
    end

  # once the order is placed just send it to the kitechn()
  def update
    @order = Order.find_by(params[:id])
    @rder.update_attributes(order_params)
    if @order.save
      render :json, order, status: 201, location: [:api, current_user.order.id]
    else
      render :json,{errors: order.errors}, status: 422
    end
  end



private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_id, :pos_id, :table_id, :order_number, 
          :order_status,:order_date, :subtotal, :final_total, :order_type, :food_item_ids => [])
  end
end
```

I am not sure, what am I doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: how are you making request to create `order` ?

Comment: G.B. I am testing this using postman.

Comment: can you also add screen shot of that request ?

Comment: what i am getting is there is some problem with your postman request.

Comment: Please see here the screen shot.
http://postimg.org/image/ils80g6nb/

Comment: you see the blue link `params` next to your URL in request click on that and see what params are being passed.

Comment: It shows me the access token in the params. Please see here.
http://postimg.org/image/nmwppcu8t/

Answer (score 0):

In your create method you use `@order = Order.build(order_params)`

And in order_params method you are expecting to have something like following {"order"=> {customer_id => 1234, order_id => 10034} .....}

Your postman request needs to change to have necessary params with order key.

Comment: The result is same even after I updated my postman URL like below.

'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/orders?access_token=testing&custmer_id=1&order_number=101'

Comment: Please try something like this order[customer_id] etc, you need to pass necessary fields what ever you are requiring here 

params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_id, :pos_id, :table_id, :order_number, 
          :order_status,:order_date, :subtotal, :final_total, :order_type, :food_item_ids => [])

Comment: It returns the below error in my controller.
undefined method `build' for #

Answer (score 0):

Your params should be in like this

```
{"access_token" => "testing", "order" => {"customer_id" => 1, "order_id" => 2, ..} }
```

Also, why there is `=> []` at the end of `order_params` method. It should just be

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_id, :pos_id, :table_id, :order_number, 
      :order_status,:order_date, :subtotal, :final_total, :order_type, :food_item_ids)
end
```

Comment: In my 'order_params'  I am passing array of ' food_items => [ ] '

' :food_item_ids ' - It contains list of food_items in a single order

Comment: But `=> []` is not required whatever be the type of data it contains

Comment: In my model order -> has_many -> food_items(which is an array)
So Shouldn't I send it as an array?

Comment: It will accept any type of data, no need to pass `=> []`

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from `ActionController::Parameters` [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) when you mark `:order` as required parameter it has to be there. Otherwise `ActionController:ParameterMissing` error will be thrown. All you need to do is to ensure you send `:order` with your request or review your requirements in `order_params` method.